# bootstrap nav-bar-right floating left

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I tried to look out for an answer for my problem but I can't seem to find one. If by any chance there actually is a solution out there, then, I'm sorry, my bad!

I seem to be encountering a problem with Bootstrap's default nav bar: The dropdown menu: `.navbar-right` is floating left for some reason. You can check it out [here](https://alpha-blog-ardzii.herokuapp.com/). 
I'm working on rails 5 and the code for my nav currently looks like:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <%= link_to "Prodemex", root_path, class: "navbar-brand", id: "logo" %>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><%= link_to "Articulos", articles_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Usuarios", users_path %></li>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Actions <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Nuevo articulo", new_article_path %></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      <% end %>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <% if logged_in? %>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Mi cuenta<%= " - Admin " if current_user.admin? %><span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Modificar mis datos", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Ver mi perfil", user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><%= link_to 'Cerrar sesión', logout_path, method: :delete %></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <% else %>
        <ul class="navbar-right nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Mi cuenta <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to 'Iniciar sesión', login_path %></li>
              <li><%= link_to 'Registrarse', signup_path %></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <% end %>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

You can retrieve more of the code on [github](https://github.com/Ardzii/alpha-blog)
I have a custom CSS with all that and already tried to delete all portions related with navbar but it did nothing...

```
$navbar-default-bg: #3498DB;

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

.gen {
  padding: 0 2%;
}

.col-xs-8 {
  float: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-weight: 200;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 200;
}

#logo:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5e82a6;
}

.navbar {
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

#home {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)), image-url('cover_page.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
}

.jumbotron {
  padding: 15.5% 20%;
  background-color: transparent;

  }

.jumbotron h1,h3 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.btn-xlg {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 200;
  background-color: #3498DB;
  border: 1px solid #3498DB;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.btn-xlge {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #000;
  background-color: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn-xlge:hover,
          active {
  background-color: #337ab7;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #337ab7;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
}

footer ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.footer a {
  color: #fff;
}

.footer a:hover,
.footer a:active {
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article-actions {
  border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.descrition {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.article-title {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.article-title a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article-body {
  border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.article-meta-details {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.article-meta-details a {
  text-decoration:none;
}

.well-lg {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.listing {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.insideuser {
  padding-left: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.author {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #3498DB;
}

.authorpage {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.pop {
  margin-top: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 1px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.27);
  -moz-box-shadow:    4px 1px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.27);
  box-shadow:         4px 1px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.27);
}
```

And the weird thing is that when I log in, the dropdown goes back to the right where it is supposed to be... 
When inspecting the code, I almost found a fix, deleting the left float to this portion:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
custom.self-839…ss?body=1:5864
.navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
```

But obviously when I do that it messes up with the rest of the navbar.
Any body can help me? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off! Thanks guys for your help! 
@Gal, your answer actually put me in the right direction and I finally found where my mistake was! (Yes, the errors is always located between the keyboard and the chair! hahhahaha!)

OK so by implementing Gal's code into my nav. I found out that the problem was coming from the fact that the problematic dropdown was considered as included in the:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

And that's when I figure that the UL wasn't closing properly! This portion was the problematic one:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><%= link_to "Articulos", articles_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Usuarios", users_path %></li>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Actions <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Nuevo articulo", new_article_path %></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      <% end %>
```

I just switch  the `</ul>` tag with the `<% end %>` one like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><%= link_to "Articulos", articles_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Usuarios", users_path %></li>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Actions <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Nuevo articulo", new_article_path %></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      <% end %>
```

and it works like a charm!

Thanks again everyone!!!

Comment: Glad to help anytime :) !!

Answer (score 1):

try to use the bootstrap grid system it will make it easy for you to position your menu items :

---

*Bootstrap column syntax -- > `class="col-[screen size]-[number of columns]"`

screen sizes ---> xs (extra small) , sm (small) , md (medium) , lg (large)

> number of columns ---> goes up to 12

---

*Move columns to the right using `class="col-md-offset-[number of columns]"` .

These classes increase the left margin of a column by a set number of columns.

For example, `class="col-md-offset-4"` moves a column over four columns.

---

*Easily change the order of our built-in grid columns with :

`class ="col-md-push-[number of columns]"` and `class ="col-md-pull-[number of columns]"`

---

[Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro)

[This video is showing the basic concept](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3LRU3JF-rQ) - This guy has a whole searies of videos ...

---

**Edited:** This is how I solved the problem of a dropdown button that was joined with the rest of the buttons ...

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills col-lg-offset-11 col-md-offset-11 col-sm-offset-11">
 <li id="btnDrpDwn" role="presentation" class="dropdown"><a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/profile">Item 1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/logout">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li></ul>
```

Comment: That's a great suggestion and it indeed might work but then it would mean that I would have to redo all the code... isn't it? 
I am currently using the default-version of the navbar which comes pretty much already loaded by bootstrap.

Comment: propably ...  but it only comes down to adding some classes. I've edited the answer and copied my menu dropdown (maybe it will help ...)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a hunch, but I thought it was worth trying...I wonder if changing where you have your if/else statement will help?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Mi cuenta<%= " - Admin " if current_user.admin? %><span class="caret"></span></a>
     <% if logged_in? %>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><%= link_to "Modificar mis datos", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
         <li><%= link_to "Ver mi perfil", user_path(current_user) %></li>
         <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
         <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
         <li><%= link_to 'Cerrar sesión', logout_path, method: :delete %></li>
       </ul>
     <% else %>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><%= link_to 'Iniciar sesión', login_path %></li>
         <li><%= link_to 'Registrarse', signup_path %></li>
       </ul>
     <% end %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I actually tried this already. I couldn't follow your specific suggestion because my <a> has an if as well relatively linked to the previous "if" statement: Hence I can't move it below. Nonetheless, I've worked a little the code and achieved the same result with a lighter version which looks pretty much like the one you posted (except for the "if" statement).

Comment: I see.  I'm curious to see how you solved this.  I was looking for a solution & it really confused me why your original code wasn't working properly.